# Wonky edge of a my graph of a plane

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to make a visual aid to teach linear programming in a high school algebra class, but my final plot has something strange going on at its edges:

```
s1 := RegionPlot[
  10 x + 20 y <= 140 && 6 x + 8 y <= 72 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, -1, 
   14}, {y, -1, 10}]
s2 := Plot3D[
  8 x + 12 y && 10 x + 20 y <= 140 && 6 x + 8 y <= 72, {x, 0, 12}, {y,
    0, 7}]
Make3d[plot_, height_, opacity_] := 
 Module[{newplot}, newplot = First@Graphics[plot];
  newplot = N@newplot /. {x_?AtomQ, y_?AtomQ} :> {x, y, height};
  newplot /. 
   GraphicsComplex[xx__] :> {Opacity[opacity], GraphicsComplex[xx]}]
Show[{Graphics3D[Make3d[s1, 0, 0.75]], s2}, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: View 1]

[image: View 2]

How can I clean that up?

Comment: It is better to give a complete but minimal examples in questions. The problem here is clearly illustrated by only this: `Plot3D[8 x + 12 y && 10 x + 20 y <= 140 && 6 x + 8 y <= 72, {x, 0, 
  12}, {y, 0, 7}]`.  It would be better to remove the irrelevant parts of the question.  In the meantime I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 15):

The problem is illustrated by this plotting command alone:

```
Plot3D[8 x + 12 y && 10 x + 20 y <= 140 && 6 x + 8 y <= 72, {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

**The syntax you are using here is simply invalid**, and the fact that it *appears* to work is merely an accident.  `And` (or `&&`) is meant to join a number of statements that can be true or false.  It makes no sense to say `3.5 && True` because 3.5 is not a truth value.  `8 x + 12 y` is not a statement.  It is an equation that has a numerical value once substituting numbers for `x` and `y`.  It has no place in a Boolean expression.

Why does plotting appear to work then?

That's because `And` is designed to also work on symbolic expressions.  You can use `a && b` the same way you use `x + y` in Mathematica.  It doesn't evaluate until `a` and `b` are given (truth) values.  The parts which do have truth values do evaluate immediately however. Thus:

```
In[]:= a && True
Out[]= a
```

This is comparable to

```
In[]:= x + 1 + 1
Out[]= 2 + x
```

The system is implemented in such a way that it doesn't care what `a` is in this expression.  If it is not a truth value, it isn't touched at all.  Thus the meaningless

```
3.5 && True
```

evaluates to

```
3.5
```

which is a number and can be used in plotting.  That's why where your condition evaluates to `True`, your expression does evaluate to a number, and can be shown by `Plot3D`.  Elsewhere the result is `False`, which is not a number and is not a value `Plot3D` expects to see.  However, `Plot3D` tries to be friendly and tolerant and just doesn't plot anything there.  This is useful in situations where the result would be `Indeterminate`, `Infinity` or a complex number.  But `False` really is meaningless here.

**The proper way to plot this** is [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction.html).

```
Plot3D[8 x + 12 y, {x, 0, 12}, {y, 0, 7}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 10 x + 20 y <= 140 && 6 x + 8 y <= 72]]
```

[image]